# How to turn a list into a complicated string

Tags: python, string, list

I want to turn this list:

```
['1','2','3','4']
```

into this string:

```
"%(1)s, %(2)s, %(3)s, %(4)s"
```

How can I do this, preferrably in ONE LINE?

Comment: This has nothing to do with embedded devices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings), [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
', '.join(['%({})s'.format(i) for i in inputlist])
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = ['1','2','3','4']
>>> ', '.join(['%({})s'.format(i) for i in inputlist])
'%(1)s, %(2)s, %(3)s, %(4)s'
```

See [List comprehension without [ ] in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024) why it is better to use a list comprehension, and not a generator expression here.

Comment: `join` can take a generator. No need to first create a `list`.

Comment: The `str.join()` method turns the generator into a list, because it has to parse the contents twice (to compute the length, then to produce the output). By using a list comprehension you gain a little performance. See [list comprehension without \[ \], Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks (although I still prefer without the comprehension, if speed is not a matter. It is just more clear - but I will definitively keep that in mind, not only for `join`). I wonder if this changes with list contents.

Comment: @Olaf: it is *specific to `str.join()` that the list comprehension is faster; it doesn't change with the contents, it is the performance difference between a list comprehension and a generator plus having to convert the latter to a list *anyway* that makes the difference here.